# Call a function in Unity Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need a script, which takes a big amount of monobehaviors in children and arranges them to lists in parent script in a specific way to save parent as prefab. It would take a eternity doing in by hand. And i dont wanna do this in Start() on runtime, because these prefabs could be instanciated a bunch times per frame and causing mini lag spikes when searching for scripts in children. So how do i do this once in a editor to save all references to prefab? Never done something like that, but seen   buttons in custom inspector that call functions for plugins. I tried [ExecuteInEditMode] which gives good result but it also continue to execute in runtime So asking what way would be simplest to just call a function in editor and make it not work in runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (!Application.isPlaying)
        {
            Debug.Log("This should only run in edit mode.");
            // More code
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on what you're trying to do exactly, there might be a better way to trigger this than `ExecuteInEditMode`, but this is the simplest way of getting the effect you requested. This won't run as long as `Application.isPlaying` returns true. So it will never run in playmode and never run in any builds.